# How to send data from view to template continously in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I need to send data from my view or my model database to my HTML/javascript template. What technology or methods should I use for that? I can't simply use for example

```
return render(request, "check_by_callsign.html", {"latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude})
```

because that would only mean one return of data.

Comment: You want to use either AJAX and continuously poll for data or use websockets and send updates from the server side.

Comment: I haven't heard of websockets until now, I will look into them, aswell as in AJAX and continuosly poll. Thank you for you recommendations!

Comment: If your constraint is to update every 5 seconds, I would recommend polling and updating your webpage every 5 seconds. It would help if your front end is already dynamic using something like View or React. Websockets are harder to implement, and you probably don't need them unless you have some serious scaling needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy to implement websockets in Django (async programming). This is being worked on, in the meantime look at [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

To poll your view every x second you can use the Fetch API within Javascript:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById('coordinates')

function fetchCoordinates() {
  fetch('yourURLhere')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => myDiv.innerHTML = data)
    }

window.addEventListener('load', event => {
  let fetchInterval = 5000; // 5 sec, 10000 = 10 sec
  setInterval(fetchCoordinates, fetchInterval);
})
```